# Concat Names against row_number() or similar function

Tags: t-sql, concatenation

my data repeats rows for individual relationships between people. For example, the below states that John Smith is known by 3 employees:

```
Person          EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson
John Smith      Derek Jones
John Smith      Adrian Daniels
John Smith      Peter Low
```

I am looking to do the following:

1) Count the number of people who know John Smith. I have done this via the row_number() function and it appears to be behaving:

```
select Person, MAX(rowrank) as rowrank
from (
            select Person, EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson, rowrank=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Person order by EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson desc)
            from Data
) as t
group by Person
```

Which returns:

```
Person          rowrank
John Smith      3
```

But now i am looking at concatenating the EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson column to return and was wondering how this might be possible:

```
Person          rowrank     EmployeesWhoKnow
John Smith      3           Derek Jones, Adrian Daniels, Peter Low
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2017+, you can use `string_agg()` in a simple group by

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Person] varchar(50),[EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('John Smith','Derek Jones')
,('John Smith','Adrian Daniels')
,('John Smith','Peter Low')

Select Person 
      ,rowrank = sum(1)
      ,[EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson] = string_agg([EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson],', ')
 From @YourTable
 Group By Person
```

**Returns**

```
Person      rowrank  EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson
John Smith  3        Derek Jones, Adrian Daniels, Peter Low
```

**If <2017 ... use the stuff()/xml approach**

```
Select Person 
      ,rowrank = sum(1)
      ,[EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson] = stuff((Select ', ' + [EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson] 
                                          From  @YourTable
                                          Where Person=A.Person
                                          For XML Path ('')),1,2,'')
 From @YourTable A
 Group By Person
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2017 +

```
select
    person,
    count(*) as KnowsCount,
    string_agg(EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson ASC) AS EmployeesWhoKnowPerson
from 
  data
group by person;
```

For prior versions:

```
select
    person,
    count(*) as KnowsCount,
    stuff((select ',' + EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson
           from data as dd
           where dd.Person = d.Person
           order by EmployeeWhoKnowsPerson
     for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS EmployeesWhoKnowPerson
from 
  data as d
group by person;
```

And you're overthinking that whole count of who knows piece.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60d24/5) with an extra name thrown in.